# Primefaces p:overlayPanel show on right click, prevent browser contextMenu?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, overlay, contextmenu

```
<p:overlayPanel showEvent="contextmenu" ..>
```

I like to show the overlay on right click. The browser also shows its context menu.
Is there a way to prevent browser showing its context menu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a javaScript function to disable browser contextMenu. Something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.oncontextmenu=function(){return false}; 
</script>
```

For your information, This technique will fail if the user disables JavaScript.